# Add plugin's plugin dependency as plugin dependency of user

Tags: plugins, sbt

I am creating an SBT plugin to be used in all Scala projects in my company. It is a collection of commonly used SBT plugins and a common configuration that can be shared everywhere. My plugin uses e.g `sbt-release`: configures credentials, sets a release process, a default publish repository, etc. So I added it as a plugin dependency

`project/plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.gseitz" % "sbt-release" % "1.0.7")
```

However I'd like to expose this plugin to my users, so they can call `sbt release`. Currently I have the following code:

`build.sbt`

```
sbtPlugin := true

/* common release configuration code */

addSbtPlugin("com.github.gseitz" % "sbt-release" % "1.0.7")
```

If I remove the last line, my user cannot call `sbt release`. However I want to avoid declaring the dependency twice. Can I do better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with a different approach, as the configurations didn't even get applied this way, and it also solves the duplication issue. Instead of sbt files, I created Scala files for the plugin and included the required plugin dependencies in `build.sbt`. This way you don't need to add it to `project/plugins.sbt` at all.

Example:

`build.sbt`

```
sbtPlugin := true

addSbtPlugin("com.github.gseitz" % "sbt-release" % "1.0.7")
```

---

`src/main/scala/mycompany/MyReleaseConfigPlugin.scala`

```
package mycompany

import sbt._
import Keys._

object MyReleaseConfigPlugin extends AutoPlugin {
  override def trigger: PluginTrigger = allRequirements
  override def requires = sbtrelease.ReleasePlugin

  /* common release configuration code example */
  import sbtrelease.ReleasePlugin.autoImport._
  import ReleaseTransformations._
  override lazy val projectSettings = Seq(
    releaseProcess := Seq[ReleaseStep](
      checkSnapshotDependencies,
      inquireVersions,
      runClean,
      setReleaseVersion,
      commitReleaseVersion,
      tagRelease,
      publishArtifacts),
    releaseIgnoreUntrackedFiles := false,
    publishMavenStyle := true,
    credentials += Credentials(
      "Artifactory Realm",
      "artifactory.mycompany.com",
      sys.env.get("REPO_USER").getOrElse(""),
      sys.env.get("REPO_PASS").getOrElse(""))
  )
}
```